# Function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html code `<input onclick="function_name(1)">` and I want to use it in Jquery something like `function function_name(i) { alert(i); }`. It doesn't work, any tips? Thank you.

Comment: What is not clear, please? I want that it would happen alert(1)

Comment: @Orbit: yes, so it isn't possible to use it in jquery with onclick on input? I just wanna know.

Comment: html onclick is an alternative to using jQuery to trigger a function. Can you provide more code or detail of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Jake: no, I don't think you need it. I just have `<input onclick="function_name(1)"` and I want through jquery that function would be called, when onclick happens. I need this, don't ask me why.

Comment: You can't define functions through jQuery. jQuery is a JavaScript library but provides nothing to help with function definitions. the code you have is plain JavaScript (which, all else being equal, should work fine)

Comment: @hey we have to ask why because your request doesn't make sense to us. We're trying to help, but if you aren't willing to supply code to use as a context, we probably won't come up with the answer you need.

Comment: @hey You don't ask mechanics for help with your car and then refuse to show them the car.

Comment: @hey: Where is the `function_name` function located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code is written, it should work.

If the `function_name` isn't firing, then it could be because you haven't defined it in the global scope.

For example, if you're using jQuery, this won't work because the function isn't global:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function function_name(i) { 
        alert(i); 
    }
});
```

But this will, because you've made the function global:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // some other code
});

function function_name(i) { 
    alert(i); 
}
```

Or this will, because you've explicitly made it global from inside `.ready()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.function_name = function(i) { 
        alert(i); 
    }
});
```

Aside from the global issue, I'm not sure why your code would fail from the `onclick=` attribute.

Comment: omg, of course it works... I am the biggest loser in the whole universe.

Comment: @hey: It's an easy and common mistake. :o)

Answer (score 4):

```
<input id="myId"/>
```

and

```
$("#myId").click(function() {
    alert('something');
});
```

If I have understood you right.

Comment: no, I have `onclick="function_name(1)` and I want alert 1.

Comment: +1 to this answer as adarshr answered the question you asked.  @hey - you cannot implement the answer as your code is written above.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

html:

```
<input data="1" id="myinput" />
```

js;

```
$('#myinput').bind('click', function(event) {

    alert($(this).attr('data'));

});
```